# How to configure CUPS to print from RedHat to a shared Windows Zebra printer TLP 3842

Tags: windows, linux, printing, zebra-printers, cups

I am trying to print from a virtual RedHat instance to a label printer shared on a Windows XP workstation.  I have had success using rlpr on Ubuntu, but we are porting to our new standard, RedHat.  Because it is virtualized, I do not have access to the CUPS administration page at *http://localhost:631* and am trying to do everything through **lpadmin**.

The Windows machine, *LC16* has Unix Print and File Sharing Services enabled (Samba?), and I'm able to print to it from Ubuntu using rlpr.

I used the following command to try to set up the CUPS printer:

**lpadmin -p 15747s_18200s -u allow:all -v lpd://LC16/15747s_18200s**

But when I run **lpq** I do not see the printer:

```
[root@here]# lpq
14415s_15747s is ready
no entries
```

My */etc/cups/printer.conf* looks like this:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.3.7
# Written by cupsd on 2011-02-15 16:01
<Printer 15747s_18200s>
Info 15747s_18200s
DeviceURI lpd://LC16/15747s_18200s
State Stopped
StateMessage
StateTime 1297810868
Accepting No
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

**lpstat -t** gives (among other stuff)

```
system default destination: 14415s_15747s
...
device for 15747s_18200s: lpd://LC16/15747s_18200s
...
15747s_18200s not accepting requests since Tue 15 Feb 2011 04:01:08 PM MST -
...
printer 15747s_18200s disabled since Tue 15 Feb 2011 04:01:08 PM MST -
    reason unknown
```

I tried to enable the printer using *cupsenable* but no luck:

```
cupsenable 15747s_18200s
```

doesn't change anything, and

```
cupsenable -h LC16 15747s_18200s
```

hangs.

Any idea what I need to do to get things running?

Thanks,

Dave Crocker